# iOS Large Title Navigation hide search bar

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a view controller which have a carousel with 3 pages. On the first page i have a collection view and want to enable the search bar in the navigation bar but on the two other pages i don't want it. So on the page selection callback i set searchcontroller to null when it's the second and third page and set it back to the searchcontroller object when it's first page.

It works well but i have no animation and the View controller doesn't resize and we can see a blank space between the view and the navigation bar when the search bar is hidden. Is there a way to achieve this properly ?

My ViewDidLoad code:

```
 public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        searchController = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null)
        {
            HidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true,
            DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false,
            //ObscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        };
        searchController.SearchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal;
        DefinesPresentationContext = true;
        NavigationItem.SearchController = searchController;
    }
```

Following the page selection callback:

```
void OnPageSelected()
    {
        if (page is IVehiclesSearchView)
        {
            NavigationItem.SearchController = searchController;           
        }
        else
        {
            NavigationItem.SearchController = null;
        }     
    }
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with only hiding `SearchBar` for `SearchController` as follow :

```
void OnPageSelected()
{
    if (page is IVehiclesSearchView)
    {
        NavigationItem.SearchController.SearchBar.Hidden = false;           
    }
    else
    {
        NavigationItem.SearchController.SearchBar.Hidden = true;
    }     
}
```

Comment: Hello, already tried but if i hide the SearchBar the NavigationBar doesnt resize and the searchbar space still showing ...

Comment: @Philoow OK , could you share a sample link here , I will check it . This can not resize automatically , it needs manually .Maybe you can add some touch event to resiez it after hiding . It depends on layout in view .